# SAPUI5 - Change the Column Name and Properties from smarttable from oData with no Annotation

Tags: sapui5

I'm developing a SAPUI5 application that's use a smart table component. But the oData provided does not send any annotations in the metatdata file. I'm starting selecting these fields from oData: PriorityName,OrderTypeType,OrderTypeName,Id,DateOpen,HourOpen,BrandName,EquipmentId,EquipmentNumber,SymptomName. But i want to show their as Priority Name, Order Type, Order Type Name, Id, Date Open, Hour Open, Brand Name, Equipment Id, Equipment Number and Symptom Name, respective, in table column header and p13ndialog.

I know that is changed by default in the sap:label property in Property Name tag under EntityType. But according the oData developer, they cant send it to me (He was using JPA and oLingo).

The code above is for my smarttable and the entity used in metadada.

```
            <smartTable:SmartTable entitySet="CustomerOrders" id="tbOrders" tableType="Table" useExportToExcel="true" beforeExport="onBeforeExport"
            header="Ordens de Manutenção" showRowCount="true" enableAutoBinding="true" beforeRebindTable="onBeforeRebindTable"
            initiallyVisibleFields="PriorityName,OrderTypeType,OrderTypeName,Id,DateOpen,HourOpen,BrandName,EquipmentId,EquipmentNumber,SymptomName"
            class="sapUiResponsiveContentPadding">
            <smartTable:customToolbar>
                <OverflowToolbar design="Transparent">
                    <ToolbarSpacer/>
                    <OverflowToolbarButton icon="sap-icon://sort" text="Sort" press="onSort"/>
                    <OverflowToolbarButton icon="sap-icon://filter" text="Filter" press="onFilter"/>
                </OverflowToolbar>
            </smartTable:customToolbar>
            <table:Table id="innerUi5Table" growing="true" selectionMode="None" visibleRowCountMode="Auto">
                <table:rowSettingsTemplate>
                    <table:RowSettings highlight="{ path: 'PriorityName', formatter: '.formatter.OrderStatusFormatter' }"/>
                </table:rowSettingsTemplate>
            </table:Table>
        </smartTable:SmartTable>
```

Metadata

```
    <EntityType Name="CustomerOrder">
<Key>
<PropertyRef Name="Id"/>
</Key>
<Property Name="BrandName" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="150"/>
<Property Name="City" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="45"/>
<Property Name="ContactFirstname" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="45"/>
<Property Name="ContactLastname" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="45"/>
<Property Name="Country" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="2"/>
<Property Name="CustomerId" Type="Edm.Int64" Nullable="true"/>
<Property Name="DateOpen" Type="Edm.DateTime" Nullable="true"/>
<Property Name="EquipmentId" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="10"/>
<Property Name="EquipmentNumber" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="12"/>
<Property Name="EquipmentType" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="40"/>
<Property Name="FantasyName" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="45"/>
<Property Name="HourOpen" Type="Edm.Time" Nullable="true"/>
<Property Name="Id" Type="Edm.Int64" Nullable="false"/>
<Property Name="Latitude" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="12"/>
<Property Name="Longitude" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="12"/>
<Property Name="ManufacturerSerialNumber" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="255"/>
<Property Name="Material" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="8"/>
<Property Name="Neighborhood" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="45"/>
<Property Name="Note" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="10"/>
<Property Name="Obs" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="150"/>
<Property Name="OrderTypeId" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="4"/>
<Property Name="OrderTypeName" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="45"/>
<Property Name="OrderTypeType" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="45"/>
<Property Name="OsImbera" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="8"/>
<Property Name="Phone" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="11"/>
<Property Name="Plant" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="4"/>
<Property Name="PriorityId" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="true"/>
<Property Name="PriorityName" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="15"/>
<Property Name="State" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="2"/>
<Property Name="Status" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="1"/>
<Property Name="Street" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="150"/>
<Property Name="SymptomId" Type="Edm.Int64" Nullable="true"/>
<Property Name="SymptomName" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="45"/>
<Property Name="SymptomObjTecnico" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="10"/>
<Property Name="SymptomSAP" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="8"/>
<Property Name="TechnicalObjName" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="255"/>
<Property Name="WarrantyObs" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="45"/>
<Property Name="WorkCenter" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="8"/>
<Property Name="Zipcode" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="9"/>
</EntityType>
```

Answer (score 0):

Redefine the rows/columns in your XML manually and bind your labels against i18n model, where you can define all the needed labels.

The bad thing about it - you cannot influence on the columns that potentially could be added via personalisation. Possible workaround - redefine ALL the columns. But in this case once the backend get changed, you have to adjust UI accordingly.